# Why is my view showing information only the first time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I have simple app with a menu on the left with just two options:

[image]

When I click on the "Servicios" option I'm loading some categories from my Parse application:

[image]

Then, if I click on the "Tablero" option and then again try to go back to "Servicios" option by clicking on the menu, the data doesn't load:

[image]

This is my controller:

```
.controller('ServicesCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.categories = {};

    // Categories
    var Category = Parse.Object.extend("Category");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Category);
    query.equalTo("isActive", true);
    query.ascending("name");
    query.find({
        success: function(categories) {
            $scope.categories = categories;
        }
    });
})
```

And this is my view:

```
<ion-view class="services-view" cache-view="false">
  <ion-nav-title>
    <span>Servicios</span>
  </ion-nav-title>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list class="list">
      <ion-item ng-repeat="category in categories" class="item item-thumbnail-left">
          <img src="img/cut.svg">
          <h2>
            {{ category.get("name") }}
          </h2>
          <p>

          </p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>    
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Do I need to do some extra work for loading again?

Comment: It may be something to do with view caching.  You can try $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function({ ... }) and altering scope within there to force a refresh...

Comment: Oh, you have cache-view false in the <ion-view> tag.  I generally use cache: t/f in the $stateProvider.  Are you sure it works as an attribute?

Comment: @Peege151 I know it's working because if I remove it then everything works fine. I still don't get the cache thing, if the data from parse has changed and I'm using cache, will the new data show? I need to make sure that if the user comes back to the view the data will be refreshed from Parse.com

Comment: No, I don't think it would show the new data if it is using cache.  It would show whatever data was loaded when the controller first loaded.  That is my understanding anyway.